# Assigned expression type string is not assignable to type boolean

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a bit problem. I have some data and some methods that do something with these data. But when i want to change a property **fixed**, i get an error.

```
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        classes: {
          titleSection: "title-section",
          fixed: false
        },
      }
    },
    methods: {
      handleScroll() {
        let coordsSection1 = this.getCoords(document.getElementById('section-1'));
        if (window.pageYOffset > coordsSection1) {
          this.classes.fixed = "fixed"; //this line get error
        }
        console.log(this.classes.fixed);
      },
      getCoords(elem) {
        let box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
          top: box.top + pageYOffset,
          left: box.left + pageXOffset
        }
      }
    },
    created() {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    },
    destroyed() {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Well, what kind of error? Edit your question with the error message.

Comment: well it starts off as false so I guess it assumes you have a Boolean. I am guessing you want to use null, not false

Comment: There is something wrong with your logic somehow, because the same code works without issue here. check it here. https://jsfiddle.net/943bx5px/5/ I only modified two minor places

Comment: You using typescript? Title doesn't look like a javascript error I'm familiar with.